# htaccess deny php permissions a directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory

I have a subfolder called thepictures which I needed write access to for people
who use the website feature to upload a picture.

I was wondering if there is a way I can put a htaccess file in that folder
that would disallow access to html and php files and such but still allow access
to gif,jpg,bmp  say ?

Any help on this is great...

Answer (score 0):

Put to the root .htaccess file : if the request URI begins with `/thepictures` but does not end with one of the specified extensions(jpeg, png and so on), it will be forboden.

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/thepictures[NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule to block access to html or php files on the given folder:

```
RewriteRule ^thepictures/.+?\.(php|html?)(/|$) - [F,NC]
```